Whatsapp API failed to send template message to 1 specific number
I'm working on Meta Whatsapp cloud API. Recently while testing it for template messages it didn't send the message for 1 number.
Although in response it gave 200 and with message "accepted" but the webhook showed "failed" to send message.
Any solutions for this ? The API is working for other numbers but giving error only for 1 number

First check whether the number is valid or not , also check it have active whatsapp account .
when ever You get webhook for that mesage you also get error code with message
you can check that for detail reason of failed message.
here is the link for error codes Whatsapp-error-codes
